# Do select()-ing for ready-to-write fds cause a busy loop?

Tags: sockets

Usually we use select() for waiting the socket which is ready to read. However, if writefds is also passed into select, then it will immediately return when fds are either readable or writable. The problem is that sockets are writable at most of the time. Won't this cause a busy loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only wait on writable when you have something to write. The same for the read - you wait for readable only when you're ready to receive data. After each successful writable check there should be `write()` and after each successful readable check there should be `read()`.

Meeting these criteria you can't introduce busy wait loop as either your stream is not infinite or the socket buffer is not infinite.